# MS Excel - Search Across Multiple Columns (Headers) and Row (Range) and Return Corresponding Matching Value based on Two Criterias

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, indexing, excel-formula

With the use of a MS Excel formula, I would like to Return Matching Values based on Two Conditions.  Search across multiple Columns (**Headers**) - `E1:K1` and match against adjacent Cell `B2` AND Match adjacent Phone Number Cell `C2` across Columns (`E2:K8`) and Return Matching Number (`E2:E8`).

[image]

Identifying and matching multiple corresponding headers and rows, with **duplicates**.  I would like to have a formula that allows **duplicates** records, while providing their unique identifier (line number).  Currently if **duplicates** are found, it returns/repeats the same first occurrence.  See illustration below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=MAP(B2:B12,C2:C12,LAMBDA(α,φ,FILTER(E2:E8,CHOOSECOLS(E2:K8,XMATCH(α,E1:K1))=φ)))
```

---

Also, not sure about the **`Excel Version`** but for older version one could use the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=INDEX($E$2:$K$8,MATCH(C2,INDEX($E$2:$K$8,,MATCH(B2,$E$1:$K$1,0)),0),1)
```

---

**Note:** The above formula needs to fill down also while exiting the edit mode one needs to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

With Duplicate Phone Numbers, in the source data:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($E$2:$E$8,CHOOSECOLS($E$2:$K$8,XMATCH(B2,$E$1:$K$1))=C2),COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)),"Not Found")
```

---

When there is a duplicate in the source data:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($E$2:$E$8)-ROW($E$2)+1)/
  (INDEX($E$2:$K$8,,MATCH(B2,$E$1:$K$1,0))=C2),COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2))),"Not Found")
```

---

When there is a duplicate :

[image]

---

```
=MAP(B2:B12,C2:C12,LAMBDA(α,φ,INDEX(FILTER(E2:E8,CHOOSECOLS(E2:K8,XMATCH(α,E1:K1))=φ),COUNTIF(D2:φ,φ))))
```

---

Comment: Mayukh, Thanks for the reply, sorry for the misdirect in my communication, as I was not aware that I didn't direct my comment to you directly.  Thanks a ton for your great formula, it works very well for my need.  In addition, is there any way to identify duplicate telephone numbers, but are located on different lines and return the respective line number?

Comment: @Miaka3 formula updated

Comment: Hi Mayukh, I updated and provided additional comments and repost for your further assistance..

Comment: @Miaka3 please check I have updated answers long back!

Comment: THANK YOU... Thank you so very much, you provided me with what I was so desperately seeking and you have now made my day... Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

edit per change of question:

`=MAP(B2:B12,C2:C12,LAMBDA(b,c,IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(E2:E8,CHOOSECOLS(E2:K8,XMATCH(b,E1:K1))=c),SUM(N(C2:c=c))),"not found")))`

Or in case lookup values for `Phone` and `Fax` can be the same lookup value (which I doubt):

`=MAP(B2:B12,C2:C12,LAMBDA(b,c,IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(E2:E8,CHOOSECOLS(E2:K8,XMATCH(b,E1:K1))=c),SUM((B2:b=b)*(C2:c=c))),"not found")))`

Comment: Thank you all, for not only your quick reply with your provided answers/solutions to my inquiry...  I've attempted using each of the mentioned formulas although each of the performed as needed, the only downside when using the "MAP" array formula, it appears that it may have limitations due to the size of the data set I'm using.  Example: I have Column Headers from E1:AZ1 and Data in Columns E2:AZ2001, and I receive an error message "CALC"..  However the INDEX/MATCH FORMULA works perfect for my need..

Comment: I don't believe map is limited to 2000 rows. What formula did you use?

Comment: I used the following example formula in my existing Worksheet:  =MAP(B2:B12,C2:C12,LAMBDA(b,c,FILTER(E2:E8,CHOOSECOLS($E$2:$K$8,XMATCH(b,E1:K1))=c))).  I will retry, as I may have possibly entered it incorrectly.   In addition, would you know of any modifications to either of the formulas including the INDEX/MATCH formula, that will return the next corresponding value if duplicate matches are identified.  Example: If in Header H2 "Phone" there are duplicate phone numbers, but on different line number, I would like for the formula to identify them separately opposed returning the same value.

Comment: Hi P.b. The FILTER($E$2:$E$8,CHOOSECOLS($E$2:$K$8,XMATCH(B2,$E$1:$K$1))=C2) formula works well without any issues, just need to figure out how to identify duplicate numbers and return the correct corresponding line number matching the data.

Comment: Add @ in front of filter `=@FILTER(...` this will return the first instance

Comment: No adding `INDEX()` in the beginning and `COUNTIFS()` at the end is what needed here. Adding `@` it will not return the other duplicates if there is more than once the phone number is listed the output data.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya you could be right, but if you're only checking by the phone number, why should the second same number in column C not list the same result as the first and if it shouldn't why should it not return the 2nd found for the 1st occurances in C? I think another search criteria is missing.

Comment: @P.b Sir, I asked OP to edit the post, as I was anticipating this, and its a usual thing, this comes in sequence the first one comes in then the second one. Its the usual `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()` with `COUNTIFS()`. But honestly i was not expecting another post to get edited after giving the solutions. Post needs to have clarity.

Comment: That changed the logic a bit; updated my answer.